# Javascript: Find clicked index with array like id

Tags: javascript

I have some `<div>` with array like id `pua[0]`, `pua[1]` etc.
How can I find the clicked index in the click event?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="gangina" id="pua[0]">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="gangina" id="pua[1]">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="gangina" id="pua[2]">&nbsp;</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var hezi=document.querySelector('#pua');

hezi.addEventListener
(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        console.log(); //I want to be able to get the clicked array id of #pua
    }

);
```

Comment: `querySelector('#pua')` won't work for those elements, since there is no element with `id="pua"`. Also, you can't `addEventListener` to a HTMLcollection (Which is what `querySelector` returns.)

Comment: @Cerbrus `querySelector` returns the first element that matches the selector. `querySelectorAll` returns a collection.

Comment: @Andreas: Oh yea, you're right! jQuery made me forget things... Still, that makes the OP's code even more broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many things wrong in the question...

If I can't beat you (don't even know which close vote to vote), I'll join you. 
Working code:

```js
var hezi = document.querySelectorAll( 'div[id^=pua]' );

Array.prototype.forEach.call( hezi, function( div ) { 
  div.addEventListener( 'click', function onDivClick ( evt ) {
     // If there are hundreds of div, put onDivClick in a variable outside forEach
     alert( evt.target.id.match( /\[(\d+)\]$/ )[1] );
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="gangina" id="pua[0]">0</div>
<div class="gangina" id="pua[1]">1</div>
<div class="gangina" id="pua[2]">2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `id="pua[0]"` use `data-` attribute to prevent from error.
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4vbkenm9/. :)

Comment: But you know, if you use `id="pua[0]"`, there will be an error, because when you select it, it's a `null` object, and you can't write `id` like this

Comment: check the example! :)

Comment: Working perfectly bro! But I do want to keep the W3C Markup Validation that is why I never use custom tags :-) https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: You can check this link! [http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html...](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)